# $_post does not contain anything

Tags: php, html, mysql

i am trying to login but it seems that my variables dont contain anthing.
i encountered this problem before but i managed to fix that , name attribute was missing  in my html form that time..but this time don't know where am i doing wrong .plz help?

here is my html snippet. its returning blank even after i submit:

```
 <form action="onlogin.php" method="post">
                <h1>Login Form</h1>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" required="" name="username" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required="" name="password" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
                    <a href="#">Lost your password?</a>
                    <a href="signup.html">Register</a>
                </div>
            </form>
```

and  my php snippet is:

```
    <?php
      include ("config/config.php");//connects to db successfully
      if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
       {
       $username =  $_POST['username']; echo "$username";
       $password =  $_POST['password']; echo "$password";
       }
    ?>***
```

Comment: you don't have $_POST['submit'], you can check if(isset($_POST['username'])) instead

Comment: thankuu so much.... now it works fine..

Answer (score 2):

You check `$_POST["submit"]` submit isset or not in php script. but you don't `send` from your form.

Try this:

```
<form action="onlogin.php" method="post">
    <h1>Login Form</h1>
    <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" required="" name="username" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required="" name="password" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log in" />
        <a href="#">Lost your password?</a>
        <a href="signup.html">Register</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Using isset to check if submit is set is bad practice. I would suggest using if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")